# Changing Default Colors of WPFToolkit Chart Control

Tags: wpf, charts, series

Does anyone know how to or found any good examples of explicitly setting the color of the data points series when using the WPFToolkit chart control?  I would like to set this as a style in my XAML.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can set the Palette on the Chart.  This example is for a ColumnSeries, but you can adapt it for whatever type you are using.

```
<charting:Chart ... Palette="{StaticResource MyPalette}">
```

The Palette definition looks like this:

```
<datavis:ResourceDictionaryCollection x:Key="MyPalette">
   <ResourceDictionary>
      <Style x:Key="DataPointStyle" BasedOn="{StaticResource ColumnSeries1Style}" TargetType="Control" />
   </ResourceDictionary>
   <ResourceDictionary>
      <Style x:Key="DataPointStyle" BasedOn="{StaticResource ColumnSeries2Style}" TargetType="Control" />
   </ResourceDictionary>
   ... add more if necessary
</datavis:ResourceDictionaryCollection>
```

The "ColumnSeries1Style" and "ColumnSeries1Style" styles define the background brush for the series:

```
<Style x:Key="ColumnSeries1Style" TargetType="Control">
   <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource Series1Brush}" />
</Style>

<Style x:Key="ColumnSeries2Style" TargetType="Control">
   <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource Series2Brush}" />
</Style>
```

You can define the brushes however you like.  Here is how to get the gradient fill used in the default charts:

```
<Color x:Key="Series1Color" A="255" R="139" G="180" B="232" />
<Color x:Key="Series1HighlightColor" A="255" R="188" G="229" B="255" />
<RadialGradientBrush x:Key="Series1Brush">
   <RadialGradientBrush.RelativeTransform>
      <TransformGroup>
         <ScaleTransform CenterX="0.5" CenterY="0.5" ScaleX="2.09" ScaleY="1.819" />
         <TranslateTransform X="-0.425" Y="-0.486" />
      </TransformGroup>
   </RadialGradientBrush.RelativeTransform>
   <GradientStop Color="{StaticResource Series1HighlightColor}"/>
   <GradientStop Color="{StaticResource Series1Color}" Offset="1"/>
</RadialGradientBrush>
```

Comment: BasedOn="{StaticResource ColumnDataPointStyle}" is not resolving...am I looking at something wrong?

Comment: Sorry about that. ColumnDataPointStyle is a custom style I defined.  You can just remove that "BasedOn".  I updated the answer.

Answer (score 4):

Just in case anybody is interested, there is a simpler way of doing it. You just need to set the DataPointStyle in the ColumnSeries and change the Background property.

```
<DVC:ColumnSeries IndependentValueBinding="{Binding Path=Key}" 
            DependentValueBinding="{Binding Path=Value}">
                <DVC:ColumnSeries.DataPointStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="DVC:ColumnDataPoint">
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="#00777F"/>
                    </Style>
                </DVC:ColumnSeries.DataPointStyle>

            </DVC:ColumnSeries>
```