# Looping through colors in binding

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, datavisualization.toolkit

I'm working on a large code project that was written by someone else, so I'm trying to add a change with as little impact as possible.  It uses `System.Windows.Controls.DataVisualization.Toolkit` to create a linechart with a number of `LineSeries` combined into one `MultiChart`, which is a class my predecessor created himself.

The lines are all the same color.  I was asked to make them different colors.  Or more than one color really.  The number of lines is not constant, so I was hoping to loop through a list of colors.  Then all I would have to do is make a large enough to cover most cases.

Because of the inconsistency in line number, I can't explicitly define each color. In addition, the `MultiChart` has a `SeriesSource` property, which is an `ObservableCollection` of multiple `LineSeries` which is in turn an `ObservableCollection` of data points, that is set via binding to the ViewModel.

So I think I'll have to bind the color to a value outside of the xaml.  Since it's view related work, I imagine the code behind would be a valid location for my color changing, but I've been unable to find a solution that works there.

I've looked at a number of question on SO and elsewhere and none of them quite worked, with or without consideration for the MVVM pattern.  I'm just looking for a working solution that I can rework into MVVM, but bonus points if it's good practice as well.

I have been working with WPF for a while now, and for some reason I can't fully wrap my head around data binding, which is likely why I've been unsuccessful with most of the solutions I found.  Despite that I think I got close with this:

In `<UserControl.Resources>`

```
<local:LocalColorConverter x:Key="MyColorConverter"/>

<Style x:Key="dataPointStyle" TargetType="{x:Type charting:LineDataPoint}">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{Binding Path=DataContext.ColorCount, 
                                              RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=local:MultiChart, Mode=FindAncestor}, 
                                              Converter={StaticResource MyColorConverter}}"/>
</Style>
```

In `LocalColorConverter.cs`:

```
class LocalColorConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        int count = (int)value;
        //SolidColorBrush returnBrush = new SolidColorBrush();
        SolidColorBrush color = new SolidColorBrush();
        switch (count % 5)
        {
            case 0:
                color.Color = Colors.Blue;
                break;
            case 1:
                color.Color = Colors.Green;
                break;
            case 2:
                color.Color = Colors.Red;
                break;
            case 3:
                color.Color = Colors.Purple;
                break;
            case 4:
                color.Color = Colors.Yellow;
                break;
        }
        return color;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

I realize this is not very good in practice.  It relies on a ColorCount value from the viewmodel, which is information relevant to the view.  Bad MVVM, but I'm just trying to get it working before I make it fit the pattern.

In addition, it doesn't really work as is, since `ColorCount` is never changed.  It's initially set to 0 in the viewmodel.  If I were to continue down this path, I would like to increment the value of ColorCount so that the colors would change each time the Converter is used.

I tried just doing `((int)value)++` before the Converter returns, but that didn't work.  I didn't think it would, but it gives you an idea of what I'm looking for.

Otherwise, I think my best solution is to do this operation in the code behind.  But I don't know where/how to do it.  It would have to change the color when the `UserControl` gets to a new `LineSeries`.  The current code behind has a `LineSeries_Loaded` event handler implemented, but the color isn't set in the line, it's set for each point in the line.  So I need to increment my color counter at each line, then use the count at each point to determine it's color.

I've tried this, but I can't seem to find the Background property this way. Note that chart is the name given to the `MultiChart` object.

```
private void LineSeries_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        foreach(LineSeries line in chart.Series.Cast<LineSeries>())
        {
            foreach(LineDataPoint point in line)
            {

            }
        }
    }
```

But I get the error that line has no public GetEnumerator.

Any suggestions?

Comment: This is wpf toolkit right? Doesn't it have support for setting the `Palette` dependency property to a StaticResource and assign colors kind of like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3703301/changing-default-colors-of-wpftoolkit-chart-control)? Been awhile since I've dinked with it so I may be wrong.

Comment: I've tried a number of options with `Palette`.  The problem is that I need to have a `Palette` for the `MultiChart`, which doesn't have that property.  It's a collection of charts.  And I can't imagine creating that property would be easy, and I've had a terrible time making dependency properties.  I wouldn't know where to start with that.

Answer (score 0):

Well, looks like writing the question got my creative juices flowing.  I remembered I tried to set the style setter in the code behind, but you can't modify the style at the loaded time.  But I just realized I can switch styles at any time.  So I made these:

```
<Style x:Key="blueDataPointStyle" TargetType="{x:Type charting:LineDataPoint}" BasedOn="{StaticResource dataPointStyle}">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Blue"/>
</Style>

<Style x:Key="redDataPointStyle" TargetType="{x:Type charting:LineDataPoint}" BasedOn="{StaticResource dataPointStyle}">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red"/>
</Style>

<Style x:Key="greenDataPointStyle" TargetType="{x:Type charting:LineDataPoint}" BasedOn="{StaticResource dataPointStyle}">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Green"/>
</Style>
```

Then, in the code behind:

```
private void UserControl_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        int count = 0;
        foreach (LineSeries line in chart.Series)
        {
            switch (count % 3)
            {
                case 0:
                    line.DataPointStyle = Resources["blueDataPointStyle"] as Style;
                    break;
                case 1:
                    line.DataPointStyle = Resources["redDataPointStyle"] as Style;
                    break;
                case 2:
                    line.DataPointStyle = Resources["greenDataPointStyle"] as Style;
                    break;
            }
            count++;

        }
    }
```

It's working! Well mostly, turns out every other line is grouped into one, so I still have some work to do.  But this is the answer for what I asked.  Plus it seems to fit MVVM.  Turns out I don't need binding(probably why I was able to come up with it).  But I am still interested in other ideas.  I would like a proper binding example.